The natural map $H^{1,0}(M)\to H^1(M)$ is injective for $M$ a compact complex surface
Let $M$ be a compact complex surface. Then On a compact complex surface, every holomorphic 1-form is closed, so the natural map $H^{1,0}(M)\to H^1(M)$ is well-defined. But why is this map injective? Injectivity is equivalent to saying that if $\psi$ is a holomorphic $1$-form which is $d$-exact, then $\psi=0$. But if $\psi=df$ for some smooth complex-valued function $f:M\to \mathbb{C}$, then $\psi=df=\partial f+\bar{\partial}f$, so $\psi=\partial f$ and $\bar{\partial}f=0$. Thus we can merely conclude that $f$ is holomorphic.
P.S. The injectivity of the map is asserted in p.128, of Zheng's book Complex Differential Geometry.

The only global holomorphic functions on a compact complex manifold are constant functions.
